# bracket on right side to the following identities and give it numbering as (*)

Tags: formatting, brackets

I want bracket on right side to the following identities and give it numbering  as (*)

```
\begin{align*}
\mu(E)&=\sup\{\mu(K)~:~ K \text{ is a compact subset of } E \}\\
&=\inf\{\mu(U)~:~ U \text{ is an open set containing } E \}
\end{align*}
```

I tried to do it as

```
\left \begin{align*}
\mu(E)&=\sup\{\mu(K)~:~ K \text{ is a compact subset of } E \}\\
&=\inf\{\mu(U)~:~ U \text{ is an open set containing } E \}
\end{align*}\right\}
```

but it shows error. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like the following, which uses an `rcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mu(E)=
\begin{rcases}
\sup\{\mu(K)\} \colon \text{$K$ is a compact subset of $E$}\\
\inf\{\mu(U)\} \colon \text{$U$ is an open set containing $E$}
\end{rcases}
\tag{$*$}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```